# How to patch value to mat datepicker of a full Date?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I have a formGroup called *dateForm* with this formControlName like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Seleziona giorno</mat-label>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date"  name = "date" [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In case I get a date from another page I need to patch this formControlName value so I do this:

```
if(this.clickedDateFromCalendar){
      this.dateForm.get('date').patchValue(this.clickedDateFromCalendar));
    }
```

But it doesn't work! When I put a random date it works

```
this.dateForm.get('date').patchValue(new Date('2/14/2021')));
```

The clickedDateFromCalendar is in this format:

```
date: Wed Jul 07 2021 10:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

In which format should it be to be used in patchValue()?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried putting your `this.clickedDateFromCalendar` to `new Date()` ? like this ? `this.dateForm.get('date').patchValue(new Date(this.clickedDateFromCalendar)));`

Comment: Yes, I've done it and it doesn't work

Comment: `this.clickedDateFromCalendar` is it an object that has a property of date ? try to make it `this.clickedDateFromCalendar.date` ?

Comment: Ok yes, i changed this.clickedDateFromCalendar to any and it works in that way. Thanks!!

Comment: well, that solved your problem, good then.